# Bluetooth programmer

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, xmega, atxmega

Someone know if there is a way to program uC via bluetooth? I'm referring to a device that receives an hex/elf file from another BT device (smartphone or PC) and sends it to a uC (xmega in this case) via PDI port.

Comment: I beleive ST8 has a serial bootloader, so you could load them with a standard BT-Serial adaptor. On a similar vein if you are using Forth, then you can load programs/develop/debug etc through the BT-serial.  e.g https://hackaday.io/project/16097-eforth-for-cheap-stm8s-gadgets/details

Answer (score 0):

Not bluetooth, but I do know of the [Segger Pro](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-pro/), with Ethernet.
Which can be connected to a tiny wireless accesspoint to make it wireless. 
[An example of a very versatile wiress accesspoint is the RBmAPL-2nD](https://mikrotik.com/product/RBmAPL-2nD)

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understand, you want to make over the air firmware upgrade by using Bluetooth. You need to write bootloader program for your main uC that receives firmware from the Bluetooth and write the received firmware to the main uC flash. When the bootloader finish its job, it needs to restart uC to execute new firmware. There is a simple project on this [link](https://www.hackster.io/youssef-sabaa/arduino-bluetooth-programming-shield-wireless-upload-code-1a397c).